# Writing a hibernation timer using systemctl hibernate

Tags: bash, sleep

I wanted to write a hibernation timer function using `systemctl hibernate` and root privileges.

This is my function:

```
hibernate-timer() {
  sudo bash -c 'echo "System is going to hibernate in $1 minute(s)..." 
  sleep $1m
  systemctl hibernate'
}
```

When running for instance `hibernate-timer 50`, I would expect the system to hibernate after 50 minutes. However, I get the following error message: `sleep: invalid time interval ‘m’`.

Can anyone tell me how I can write a hibernation timer using root privileges?

Comment: Read the info about the hibernate tag. It's not what you think it is, and is inappropriate for your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to pass the parameter to `bash -c` after the single quotes:

```
hibernate-timer() {
  sudo bash -c 'echo "System is going to hibernate in $1 minute(s)..." 
  sleep $1m
  systemctl hibernate' -- $1
}
```

Notice the `-- $1` I added near the end. Without this, the command in `bash -c` is not getting any command line arguments, so the value of `$1` inside the command is empty, so instead of `sleep 50m` the command becomes `sleep m` which won't work.

From the man page:

```
   --        A  --  signals the end of options and disables further option
             processing.  Any arguments after the -- are treated as  file‐
             names and arguments.
```

This is how the `-- $1` there gets passed in as argument for the command within `bash -c '...'`

Comment: Thanks janos. Have you tried it yourself? For me it is not working and presents me with the same error message as above.

Comment: Now it is perfectly working. Thanks a bunch! What does the `--` do in this context and why cannot it be ommited?

Comment: @orschiro Awesome :-) I updated my answer with explanation of `--`.